# Firebase iOS data observers not responding periodically on iPhone

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase *data observers in our iOS app stopped responding* since couple of days. Works fine on simulator but hangs on the real devices.

Nothing in our app has changed since, and we're clueless as to what made Firebase behave this way.

Our usage well within the current plan quotas. We saw this issue for the whole of the last week of last month. Mysteriously, all started working normally since 1st of April, **precisely for a week** till yesterday.

Could anyone guide us through to resolve? We tried some workarounds from the community about the same issue e.g. disabling bitcode but they didn't work.

Comment: Check if you are using persistence cache enabled. Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true. If it's enabled it will get data from the cache. The data won't refresh

Comment: Yes, we've enabled persistence. Issue is that everything works fine on simulator or if we connect device directly to XCode, but not when we deploy build through Testflight or similar, periodically.

Comment: Yup mostly it's the problem.  Try setting it off and test. If you really want to use persistence cache at a time use keepSyncing attribute

Comment: Sure, will try and see if that solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Sivajee disabling cache didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got the issue resolved. It was related to auth token issue.

Saw more info about the actual issue by enabling logging in Firebase, through

```
FIRDatabase.setLoggingEnabled(true)
```

In the logs we saw messages:

*Error fetching token: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17011 "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., error_name=ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND}*

We were fetching some useful information ("/metadata/*") from Realtime Database before user logged (essentially auth is empty). Our database rules allow it:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "metadata": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }

    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
}
```

Though our database rules allow that access, Firebase was bent on authToken, perhaps due to the default 'auth != null' rule protecting all the others.

We resolved the issue now by fetching even the metadata after the signIn, and everything is just fine.

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen to you after app update? - I'm having this kind of issue as well... in my case the completion block is not called.
I'm writing answer because I don't have reputation to post as a comment.

Comment: Can't say for sure. It happens sporadically; just worked for a week before it stopped.

Comment: "Issue is that everything works fine on simulator or if we connect device directly to XCode, but not when we deploy build through Testflight or similar, periodically." I have the same issue when i deliver via TestFlight

Comment: @Ravi can you show here a snippet with the autologin system? I think there is a token invalidation issue there.

Comment: Didn't get you. Our Realtime Database authentication is turned off and the app is now stuck fetching some generic (not account specific) data itself. So not sure if the token has any relevance in our case.

Comment: Just answered. Please check if your case fell into the same bucket as ours.