# Swift: Proper Firebase error-handling

Tags: swift, firebase, error-handling, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm not able to understand why neither print lines are executed when running the following code:

```
ref.child("schools/\(schoolTextField.text!)/settings/pin").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value)
}, withCancel: { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
})
```

It used to work, until I made some changes regarding firebase authentication, but I don't see why the `withCancel` block is not executed!

How do I catch whatever error is occuring here? No error-message is printed in the log.

**EDIT:**
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315543/firebase-ios-data-observers-not-responding-periodically-on-iphone) which suggests that the problem might be related to the authentication after all. In `appDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I check if the user auth-token exists in Firebase Auth:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion: { (response, error) in
    guard error == nil, let uid = response else {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    ...
})
```

In current case there is an error, which is printed:

`Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17011 "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."`

I'm now also getting these errors printed in the log:

`[Common] _BSMachError: port b43b; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
[Common] _BSMachError: port b43b; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"`

Comment: Can you provided more code and what you want to achieve

Comment: Updated my post with further info!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
 for snap in snapshots {

  print("SNAP: \(snap)")

}
```

Also The error code *17011* is a user not found error see [FIRAuthErrorCode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode) for more info also it's better you create a Dataservice class to handle your interaction with firebase see [Creating A Reusable Firebase Data Service](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-reusable-firebase-data-service-part-i-harrison-ferrone) for more info.